# How to insert Json Data into Html Divs?

Tags: javascript, html, json

This is my json file "contact.json"

```
[
   {
      "name":"Alice",
      "surname":"Smith"
   },
   {
     "name":"Bob",
      "surname":"Walter"
   }
]
```

What I try to achieve is to read this file with javascript (+jquery) populate html divs (based on number of contacts) and place the name and surname in divs.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Test">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="people.json"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

     <section id="contacs">
       <div class="grid-3">               
            <div class="box">
                   <h3 class="name"></h3>
                   <h3 class="surnamename"></h3>                         
             </div>                               
       </div>
     </section>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Here what I have written so far;

```
load();

function load(){

var name=document.querySelector(".name");
var surname=document.querySelector(".surname");

    $.getJSON("contact.json", function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
       console.log(value);
       name.innerHTML= value.name;
       surname.innerHTML= value.surname;


    });
});
```

So I can get the contacts write them in console how ever I cant pass them into innerHTML and dont know how to populate Html divs called "box".

Comment: Have you heard of anything like EJS... Moustache... etc? ... They're basically JS template tools, or you could use one I've batched up prior to now?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create elements through your js in next way:

```
document.createElement('div')
document.createElement('h3')
```

To change text there you use

```
block.innerHTML = "Put your code here"
```

And to fill it with other blocks you use

```
block.appendChild(otherBlock)
```

Here's small example, hope it will help you: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jQGBdm

Answer (score 0):

One possible fix:

```
var myDiv = document.createElement("div");   
myDiv.innerHTML = "<h3>" + value.name + "</h3> \
               <h3>" + value.surname + "</h3>"   

document.body.appendChild(myDiv);
```

UPDATE: (best practice)

```
var markup = `
<div class="box">
       <h3 class="name">${value.name}</h3>
       <h3 class="surname">${value.surname}</h3>                         
 </div>
`;

document.body.innerHTML = markup;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give Id to the parent `div` say **container**, create dynamic `h3` elements and append it to parent `div`

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Test">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="people.json"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

     <section id="contacs">
       <div class="grid-3" id="container">               
            <div class="box">
                   <h3 class="name"></h3>
                   <h3 class="surnamename"></h3>                         
             </div>                               
       </div>
     </section>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Jquery:

```
var data = [
   {
      "name":"Alice",
      "surname":"Smith"
   },
   {
     "name":"Bob",
      "surname":"Walter"
   }
];

load();

function load(){

var name=document.querySelector(".name");
var surname=document.querySelector(".surname");

    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        var parent = document.createElement('div');
      parent.className = 'box';
      var $name = $('<h3 class="name">').text(value.name);
      var $surname = $('<h3 class="surname">').text(value.surname);
      $name.appendTo(parent);
      $surname.appendTo(parent);
      $(parent).appendTo($('#container'));
    });
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jzrdoh7w/1/)